# Is it possible to retrieve the Switch mac address using LLDP and SNMP?

Tags: snmp, mac-address

In order to discover the topology of a fully-interconnected-switched network which contains no routers, and divide the network into some VLANs depending on the switch they are physically connected to, I needed to detect firstly if two nodes are connected physically to the same switch.

Since, switches don't rewrite Ethernet frames, and don't leave their own signature on traversing frames, I needed to use LLDP because there is no other reliable mean (Of course there are some special configuration to be done on the switch to avoid traversing LLDP frames).

So, each switch should firstly broadcast LLDP frame which is to be stored in the MIB of the processes.

My Question: Is it possible (from machine A1 connected to switch A) to know the MAC address of the switch connected to machine Xn by using SNMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.
With SNMP and LLDP it is possible to map the entire network.
However, this requires that all devices and switches in the network actually support both SNMP and LLDP, and have it enabled.
Unmanaged switches typically have no support for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. would you please provide me with the needed steps over a managed switch so that I could search for them step-by-step.

Comment: I would basically have to recite the LLDP and SNMP specifications for you.
The specifications are available online. Have a go at implementing your program, and ask specific questions on stack overflow if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

May be its too late to give you the answer. The chassis id tlv usually gives you the MAC address. The oid for the chassis id is 1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.3.2.0. you can run this command:
snmpwalk -c public -v 2c switch_ip 1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.3.2.0